# How to deal with frequencies that don't appear in the held-out set?

Tags: smoothing, frequency, train

The held out probability is defined as $$P_{HO}\left(x\right)=\frac{t_{r}}{N_{r}\cdot\left|S^{H}\right|}$$ where:

- $t_{r}$ is the total number of times events that appeared $r$ times in the training set appeared in the held-out set: $$t_{r}=\sum_{x:C^{T}\left(x\right)=r}C^{H}\left(x\right)\,.$$
- $N_{r}$ is the number of different events that appeared $r$ times in the training set. $$N_{r}=\left|\left\{ x\middle|C^{T}\left(x\right)=r\right\} \right|$$
- $\left|S^{H}\right|$ the size of the held-out set.

The idea is to take less from the high-frequency events, because we assume they are high-frequency by right (and not by chance) and therefore that they'll be high frequency in the held-out set as well.

**Question:**
But what happens when a frequency appears in the training set but not in the held-out set?

For example, the word "the" may appear $23532$ times in the training set but $23533$ times in the held-out set. With frequencies this large, it's possible that the held-out does not contain any event that appears $23532$ times, and thus:

$$P_{HO}\left("the"\right)=\frac{t_{r}}{N_{r}\cdot\left|S^{H}\right|}=\frac{t_{23532}}{N_{23532}\cdot\left|S^{H}\right|}=\frac{0}{N_{23532}\cdot\left|S^{H}\right|}=0$$

Even though "the" is quite frequent a word.

What am I missing?

Comment: Doesn't an event which occurs $z$ times, need to occur $z-1$, $z-2$, $z-3$, etc. untill $z-i = 1$ times as well? What I mean to say is, If some event occurred 10 times, you can be really sure (100%) this event has also occurred 9 times, 8 times, 7, times, 6 times, etc., and 1 time at least once before it occurred 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

$t_{23532}=23533$, according to the definition you wrote for $t_r$.

$$t_{23532}=\sum_{x:C^{T}\left(x\right)=23532}C^{H}\left(x\right)\,$$

Assuming $x="the"$ is the only word that $C^T\left(x\right)=23532$:

$$=C^{H}\left("the"\right)=23533$$

Comment: This needs further elaboration to be understood.

Comment: This answer is cryptic on it's own, but makes sense if I read it after @IWS' answer.

Comment: I think that I pointed to the point you missed. Is not it?